# having trouble with groupby and sum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Good evening guys. I'm currently developing a web application with the use of asp.net mvc and C# and I'm having trouble with using the groupby() and sum(). I'm attaching a screenshot of the output to better understand the situation i'm in.
[image: Screenshot1]

what I want to do here is to group all with the same description and the total is to be summed. I have tried groupby and sum but i cant seem to arrive at the desired output. Can anyone please give me some good points on how to do this?

here is the codes i have tried in the manager:

```
    public IEnumerable<TuitionFeeRevenuePerProgramVM_L> getDetails(string orgUnit, short? academicYear, byte? academicPeriod)
    {
        var depts = getAllOrgUnitDepByOrgUnitSchID(orgUnit);

        var revenue = tuitionFee.SearchFor(x => x.AcademicPeriod == academicPeriod && x.AcademicYear == academicYear && depts.Contains(x.Course.OrgUnitCode) && x.IsLatest == true, "AssessmentItem.ChartOfAccount,AssessmentItem.ChartOfAccount.CostCenter,Course,Course.CourseSchedule,Course.OrgUnit,Course.OrgUnit.OrgUnitHierarchy1,Course.OrgUnit.OrgUnitHierarchy1.OrgUnit").ToList();

        var r = revenue.GroupBy(x => x.Course.OrgUnitCode).Select(x => x.First()).ToList(); //this line seems to group them but the output is the first total amount not the overall total

        var rev = revenue.Select(x => new TuitionFeeRevenuePerProgramVM_L
        {
            CostCenterCode = x.AssessmentItem.ChartOfAccount.CostCenterID,
            CostCenterDesc = x.Course.OrgUnit.OrgUnitDesc,
            Subjects = getNumberOfSubjects(x.Course.OrgUnitCode, x.AcademicYear, x.AcademicPeriod),
            Enrolees = revenue.Where(y => y.Course.OrgUnitCode == x.Course.OrgUnitCode).Select(z => z.Course.CourseSchedule.Sum(a => a.EnrolledStudents)).Sum(b => b.Value),//(int)x.Course.CourseSchedule.Sum(y => y.EnrolledStudents),
            Total = (decimal)((x.Course.CourseSchedule.Sum(y => y.EnrolledStudents) * x.Amount) * x.Course.ContactHrs) /*(revenue.Where(y => y.Course.OrgUnitCode == x.Course.OrgUnitCode).Select(z => z.Course.CourseSchedule.Sum(a => a.EnrolledStudents)).Sum(b => b.Value) * revenue.Where(d => d.Course.OrgUnitCode == x.Course.OrgUnitCode).Sum(e=>e.Amount)) * revenue.Where(f => f.Course.OrgUnitCode == x.Course.OrgUnitCode).Sum(g=>g.Course.ContactHrs) //*/
        });

        return rev.ToList();
    }
```

the controller,model and view is as is since all the logic involved will be placed in the manager. I have tried to use Sum() when returning but it gets an error since the controller receives a list and not a decimal.

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: will be posting it right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
from d in data 
group d by d.Description into g
from gg in g 
select new {Description = gg.Key, Sum = gg.Sum(ggg=>ggg.TotalCost)}
```

Something like that without seeing the data class